# Java class method defines String type, takes int as param and returns null

Tags: java, types

Just getting into some Java for now. Saw this extended class in the OCA 7 book and just wondered how it's possible that class Baz uses the go method and expects return type String but the argument takes an int. The return is then null.

Is Baz a legal construction or will this return compile error? I mean it returns type String, but takes an int argument and then returns null. How is that possible?

```
public class Foo {
    void go() {}
}

public class Baz extends Foo {
    String go(int x) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `go()` and `go(int)` are quite [different methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). Don't be confused that they have the same name. Their signature is different.

Comment: @dhke I don't think he cares about the inheritance at all. He is just confused that it can return `null` when it should return a `String`.

Comment: "Is Baz a legal construction or will this return compile error?" Well, what happened when you tried it?

Comment: This is from the book, I'm not using an IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Baz` extends `Foo` it will inherit `Foo`'s `go()` method.

Additionally `Baz` declares its own method called `go(int x)` with a return type of `String`. These are two different methods and the compiler treats them as such, since they have a different [signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) (= name + parameter types). If the only difference was the return type then you'd get a compilation error.

Because the signature is different the compiler can always tell which method you want to call - in this case depending on whether you pass an `int` as a parameter when calling `go` or not.

This is why `Baz` is a fully valid Java class.

Edit: `go(int x)` can return `null` because `String` is a class. You can always pass/return `null` when a reference to an instance of a class is expected. (The method parameter doesn't matter at all for why this is possible)

Comment: yes it's meant to return type String, but take an int argument and then returns null. How can that be possible?

Comment: @emporio The argument is totally irrelevant to the return type. The only reason for the argument is to be able to pass information into the method - regardless of what you do with it.

Comment: Yes so when the end returns a null, that's legal.